# Trouble Installing DBD::mysql

Tags: mysql, perl, installation, cpan

I'm attempting to install DBD::mysql, and it's failing because it cannot log into the SQL server. I have put a my.cnf in /root for the duration of the installation. I can't log in specifying mysql without '-p'. However, I can do this with a non-root account that has a my.cnf in place. I'm assuming the my.cnf would let the CPAN tests log in, which is the cause of the installation failure.

I don't want to force install this module, and I am not quite sure how to get this to install properly.

Answer (score 3):

See [DBD::mysql::INSTALL](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBD-mysql/lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod#Environment-Variables):

> #### Environment Variables
>
> For ease of use, you can set environment variables for DBD::mysql installation. You can set any or all of the options, and export them by putting them in your .bashrc or the like:

The relevant ones are:

```
export DBD_MYSQL_TESTDB=test
export DBD_MYSQL_TESTHOST=localhost
export DBD_MYSQL_TESTPASSWORD=s3kr1+
export DBD_MYSQL_TESTPORT=3306
export DBD_MYSQL_TESTUSER=me
```

Of course, customize the values for your situation.